# Why/how does a SwiftUI view's identity depend on the value of its `@StateObject` member variable?

Tags: swiftui, core-data

In this example a SwiftUI view's identity depends on the value of its `@StateObject` member variable. I don't think this should be possible because if a view doesn’t have an explicit identity, it has a structural identity based on its type and position in the view hierarchy. In the example below the `ItemPopupView`'s identity depends on the value of its `itemsWrapper` member. Please help me to understand this and hopefully to change the view that its `itemsWrapper` member doesn't impact the view's identity.

Please note that in this Minimal Reproducible Example the `itemsWrapper` `StateObject` isn't used, but the point of the MRE is to understand and address this identity issue.

To reproduce:

1. Add a core data model named `TestApp` with an entity named `Item` that has 1 `Date` attribute named `updateTime`.
2. Run the app
3. Tap the row in the list
4. Tap the Edit button in the sheet that opens
5. Tap the Save button in the next sheet that opens
6. Observe that `ItemPopupView: @self changed.` **was** printed in the console
7. Comment out the `_itemsWrapper =` line in `ItemPopupView`'s `init()`
8. Rerun the app, tap the row, tap Edit, tap Save
9. Observe that `ItemPopupView: @self changed.` **wasn't** printed in the console

Apologies this code is so long, I couldn't find a way to minimize it further:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct TestAppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var manager: DataManager = DataManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ItemListContentView()
                .environmentObject(manager)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, manager.container.viewContext)
                .onAppear() {
                    let item = Item(context: manager.container.viewContext)
                    item.updateTime = Date()
                    try? manager.container.viewContext.save()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildContextAndObject<Object: NSManagedObject>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var childObject: Object?
    
    init(withExistingObject object: Object?, in parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    ) {
        self.childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = parentContext
        self.childObject = childContext.object(with: object!.objectID) as! Object
    }
}

class DataManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var containerImpl: NSPersistentContainer? = nil
    
    var container: NSPersistentContainer {
        if containerImpl == nil {
            containerImpl = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestApp")
            containerImpl!.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            containerImpl!.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        }
        return containerImpl!
    }
}

struct ItemPopupItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var item: Item?
}

struct ItemListContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @State var popupItem : ItemPopupItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text("\(item.updateTime!)")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        popupItem = ItemPopupItem(item: item)
                    }
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
                .sheet(item: $popupItem) { popupItem in
                    ItemPopupView(popupItem: popupItem)
                }
        )
    }
}

class ItemsWrapper : ObservableObject {
    public var items : [Item] = []
    
    init() {
    }
    
    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}

struct ItemPopupView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    var popupItem : ItemPopupItem
    @StateObject var itemsWrapper = ItemsWrapper()
    @State public var updateOperation: ChildContextAndObject<Item>?
    
    init(popupItem : ItemPopupItem) {
        self.popupItem = popupItem
        _itemsWrapper = StateObject(wrappedValue: ItemsWrapper(items: [popupItem.item!])) // effects identity
    }

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        VStack {
            Button("Edit") {
                updateOperation = ChildContextAndObject(withExistingObject: popupItem.item!, in: viewContext)
            }
            Text("\(popupItem.item!.updateTime!)")
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
            .sheet(item: $updateOperation) { updateOperation in
                EditItemView(item: updateOperation.childObject!)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, updateOperation.childContext)
            }
        )
    }
}

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
  
    var body: some View {
        Button("Save") {
            print("save")
            item.updateTime = Date()
            try? viewContext.save()
            try? viewContext.parent!.save()
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have no need for `@StateObject` in this case because aren't doing anything async with Combine or with a delegate. Try making `DataManager` a struct and remove `ItemsWrapper`. Objects in SwiftUI are generally inefficient with updates as you found.

Comment: Hi, thank you for considering. I can`t remove the StateObject as I am using it in my real app, however this Minimal Reproducible Example does not require that usage.

Comment: In your real app can you move whatever you have in `@StateObject` into a `NSManagedObjectContext` extension or your `NSManagedObject` subclasses?

Comment: No I can't because it's state. My real question here is how it's possible that whether or not a @StateObject member variable is initialized impacts SwiftUIs logic for computing the identity of the view.

Comment: @self changed doesn't mean identity changed it means a let has changed, in your case popupItem

Comment: I see the doc says `@self marks the change to the view value` but in this case none of the lets or vars of the View changed. A field in an object in the itemsWrapper member's array changed.

Comment: Try removing `overlay(EmptyView()` and `itemsWrapper = StateObject(wrappedValue: ItemsWrapper(items: [popupItem.item!]))` both are non standard